# How to select multiple random elements from a LUA table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm trying to figure out how to randomly select multiple entries in a table.

This is what I have currently

```
local letters = {"w", "x", "y", "z"}


function randomletterselect()
    local randomletters = {}
    
    for i,v in pairs(letters) do
        table.insert(randomletters,i)
    end
    local letter = letters[randomletters[math.random(#randomletters)]]
    -- set multiple selected letters to the new table?

end
randomletterselect()
```

this code here  works for selecting ONE random element(letter) from the table. essentially, when I run this, I want it to be multiple random letters selected. for example, one time it may select x,y another time it may be x,y,z.

The closest thing I found was honestly just what I had figured out, in this post [Randomly select a key from a table in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22321277/randomly-select-a-key-from-a-table-in-lua)

Comment: How does it decide how many letters to return? Should there be a function parameter for that? And is the function allowed to select duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can do...

```
randomletterselect=function()
local chars={}
for i=65,math.random(65,90) do
  table.insert(chars,string.char(math.random(65,90)):lower())
end
print(table.concat(chars,','))
return chars
end

randomletterselect()
```

...for lowercase letters.

And this version returns a table without doubles...

```
randomletterselect=function()
local chars=setmetatable({},{__name='randomletters'})
for i=65,90 do
  table.insert(chars,string.char(i):lower())
end
for i=1,math.random(#chars) do
 table.remove(chars,math.random(#chars))
end
print(#chars,table.concat(chars,','))
return chars
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local tbl = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'} -- your characters here

local MIN_NUM, MAX_NUM = 1, 2 ^ #tbl - 1
-- if the length of the table has changed, MAX_NUM gonna change too

math.randomseed(os.time())

local randomNum = math.random(MIN_NUM, MAX_NUM)

local function getRandomElements(num)
    local rsl = {}
    local cnt = 1
    
    while num > 0 do
        local sign = num % 2 -- to binary
        -- if the num is 0b1010, sign will be 0101

        num = (num - sign)/2
        
        if sign == 1 then
            local idx = #rsl + 1
            -- use tbl[#tbl + 1] to expand the table (array)
            
            rsl[idx] = tbl[cnt]
        end
        
        cnt = cnt + 1
    end
    
    return table.concat(rsl)
end

print(getRandomElements(randomNum))
```

I have another method to solve the problem, try.
MIN_NUM should be 1 cuz when its 0, getRandomElements will return an empty string